# Why is signal SIGABRT ignored in Child Process

Tags: linux, unix

We have a Linux service process which spawns a child process using fork, then runs execelp to execute another program.  When we run a command "kill -6 [child_pid]" it has no effect.   The same command will kill the child program if it is run by itself, so we are pretty sure the signal is being processed by the system in this case.  So why is it not being received by the child process when it is under the control of te service process?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

And this is happening in RedHat Linux and CentOS.

And the core file size is set to unlimited.

Also I would like to mention that the same command works on the parent process, so we know parent does not handle (ignore) SIGABRT.  The parent is run by a shell script (bash).  So in running command "ps", I see shell script pid, parent pid and child pid.  the command works on the parent pid, and the shell script pid.

And my understanding is even though child process inherits signal handlers, after execlp the child program does not.

Comment: Your understanding is not correct...  The [exec family](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) of functions will cause the child to inherit both ignored and blocked signals.  There is no magic here; either the kernel is buggy (very unlikely) or the child is blocking or ignoring `SIGABRT`.  There are no other possiblities.

Answer (score 2):

Citing from `man sigaction`:

> A child created via fork(2) inherits a copy of its parent's signal dis‐
>          positions.   During  an  execve(2), the dispositions of handled signals
>          are reset to the default; the dispositions of ignored signals are  left
>          unchanged.

So my guess is that the service process is set up to ignore the SIGABRT, and this is inherited by the child.

Answer (score 0):

The child process inherits its signal mask from the parent at the time of the `fork`.

So I would speculate that your parent process is blocking SIGABRT (via [sigprocmask or pthread_sigmask](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_sigmask.html)).

Comment: As my edited question mentions, the parent process actually does not ignore or block SIGABRT, so the inheritance should not matter here.  But the question remains as to why the signal is not being received by the child program?